# How to point mail to a host service with cPanel?

Tags: dns, cpanel, digital-ocean

My site is in a VPS of Digital Ocean: (let’s say IP 1.1.1.1)

mydomain.com has nameservers of Digital Ocean

I want that “mail” goes to my account at Host Gator

So I add this:

“A record” mail.mydomain.com to 2.2.2.2 (the IP of my Host Gator)

“mx record” mail.mydomain.com

I think that’s all right but now, what do I have to do in cPanel of Host Gator?

Do I have to use the “Addon Domain”?

If yes: Do I have to add/delete/change zone or mx records?

If no: How do I add records and email accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to change MX record on your  Host Gator server but you need to create your all mail account on your  Host Gator account to use mail service of  Host Gator server

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand, could you be more specific?

Comment: You just need to create your mail account on your hostgator account.